# How to find or create headers in xlsx in Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am writing a code that has a lot of keys (AVIGILON, HID, FARGO, GENETEC, RS2, SYNERGIS HARDWARE etc). What I want to do is that whenever I get a value along with that key in a dictionary, I want to go to the xlsx file and find the header,and if found, place it under. But if I do not find the header, (Let's say the FARGO is being fetched for the first time and we need to enter it with a value of 1010), I want to create a new header of FARGO and place the 1010 value under it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQajp.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZxu5.png)

I am not sure how to do it. I did with other method which is long and time consuming. Is there any better and faster way to accomplish the goal?

Comment: If you use pandas, I think you can use `dataframe.columns` and save it to a variable if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain a dictionary with the headers against the colum then compare the new dict entry to the header dict. If the header exists already get the column to add to or use the length of the header dict to know what is the next column to add the new header to.
The code example below adds four dictionaries to the example sheet in the image. It will append the value to the corresponding column if it exists or create and append if not.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import utils

excelfile = 'foo.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excelfile)
ws = wb['Sheet1']

dictlist = [
{'AVIGILON': 123, 'HID': 124, 'FARGO': 125},
{'GENETEC': 126, 'RS2': 127, 'SYNERGIS': 128, 'HARDWARE': 129},
{'GENETEC': 226, 'SYNERGIS': 228, 'FARGO': 225, 'RS2': 227},
{'AVIGILON': 323, 'SYNERGIS': 328, 'FARGO': 325, 'HID': 224}
]

### Get a list of headers
header = {c.value.strip(): c.column for c in ws[1]}

for dict in dictlist:
    for k, v in dict.items():
        if k not in header:
            ### The key from the dictionary is not in the sheet
            col = len(header)+1
            ### Add header name into row 1
            ws.cell(row=1, column=col, value=k)
            ### Update header dict to include the new header
            header[k] = col

        ### Get the last used row in the current column (last cell with value)
        max_row_column = max((c.row for c in ws[utils.get_column_letter(header[k])] if c.value is not None))
        ### Append value from dict to the next free row in the column
        ws_cell = ws.cell(row=max_row_column+1, column=header[k], value=v)

wb.save(excelfile)
```